# Distinct Dates with its highest value from an object with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have something like this:

```
data = [
  {
    DateMeasured:"2018-08-27T04:46:25",
    Steps:100
  },
  {
    DateMeasured:"2018-08-27T04:46:25",
    Steps:500
  },
  {
    DateMeasured:"2018-08-27T04:46:25",
    Steps:800
  },
{
    DateMeasured:"2018-08-26T04:46:25",
    Steps:400
  },
{
    DateMeasured:"2018-08-26T04:46:25",
    Steps:300
  },
{
    DateMeasured:"2018-08-25T04:46:25",
    Steps:100
  }
];
```

I have an object of data like above, now I want to recreate object with discrict dates but its highest steps, but now i want like this:

```
data = [
  {
    DateMeasured:"2018-08-27T04:46:25",
    Steps:800
  },
{
    DateMeasured:"2018-08-26T04:46:25",
    Steps:400
  },
{
    DateMeasured:"2018-08-25T04:46:25",
    Steps:100
  }
];
```

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: what do you mean by distinct? do youlike to add all steps for a day, or from every day the highest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce the array by checking the last inserted object with the same date and if not found, insert the object, otherwise check the value and update the array with a greater `Step` property.

```js
var data = [{ DateMeasured: "2018-08-27T04:46:25", Steps: 100 }, { DateMeasured: "2018-08-27T04:46:25", Steps: 500 }, { DateMeasured: "2018-08-27T04:46:25", Steps: 800 }, { DateMeasured: "2018-08-26T04:46:25", Steps: 400 }, { DateMeasured: "2018-08-26T04:46:25", Steps: 300 }, { DateMeasured: "2018-08-25T04:46:25", Steps: 100 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var index = r.findIndex(({ DateMeasured }) => DateMeasured === o.DateMeasured);
        if (index === -1) {
            r.push(o);
            return r;
        }
        if (r[index].Steps < o.Steps) {
            r[index] = o;
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort by the number of steps and take the first 3 elements:

```js
const data = [ { DateMeasured:"2018-08-27T04:46:25", Steps:100 }, { DateMeasured:"2018-08-27T04:46:25", Steps:500 }, { DateMeasured:"2018-08-27T04:46:25", Steps:800 }, { DateMeasured:"2018-08-26T04:46:25", Steps:400 }, { DateMeasured:"2018-08-26T04:46:25", Steps:300 }, { DateMeasured:"2018-08-25T04:46:25", Steps:100 } ];

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => b.Steps - a.Steps)
const takeFirst3 = sorted.slice(0, 3)

console.log(takeFirst3)
```